# Graphene-Django nested filters (relay)

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to achieve the following using graphene-django's `DjangoFilterConnectionField`:

```
{
  allUsers(username_Icontains: "abc") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        demographics (name_Icontains: "xyz") {
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know that in graphene django, it's possible to have nested filtering using [graphene's List](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/431) 
But I'm not sure if I can work this out using `DjangoFilterConnectionField`.

I have the following graphene (relay) schema:

```
class UserNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (Node,)
        filter_fields = {
            'username': ['exact', 'icontains', 'in'],
        }

class DemographicNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Demographic
        interfaces = (Node,)
        filter_fields = {
            'name': ['icontains'],
        }

 class Query(ObjectType):

    user = Node.Field(UserNode)
    all_users = DjangoFilterConnectionField(UserNode)

    demographic = Node.Field(DemographicNode)
    all_demographics = DjangoFilterConnectionField(DemographicNode)
```

In the [docs](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial-relay/#schema) it's suggested to introduce each filter on the connected node as well. So it would be like this:

```
class UserNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (Node,)
        filter_fields = {
            'username': ['exact', 'icontains', 'in'],
            'demographic__name': ['icontains']
        }
```

But I think there must be a better way to do this since I have to do this for more than 20 nested Nodes.

Comment: This is far from ideal, but maybe you can get `DemographicNode._meta.filter_fields` and add them to the `UserNode` (perhaps in `UserNode`'s `__init__`), prepending  `demographic__`?

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will end up doing that as a last resort.

Comment: Having the same issue as you. I came from `django rest framework` (DRF) and nested filtering works out of the box with `django-filter`, I only needed to specify `fields` on each parent & child FilterSet meta class, no double underscore needed at all. But `graphene-django` seems not supporting this, so you have to specify all the nested fields at the parent FilterSet and use double underscore there. The fact that it's ignoring the meta info in the child FilterSet could lead to duplicated code, especially when the child FilterSet is reused by multiple parent FilterSet.

Comment: @ShaungCheng Could you provide code for what you are suggest above, I am having the same issue, but cannot seem to find a solution to it.

Comment: Hey @Ross it's been 2 years ago but lucky enough, I was able to locate the relevant code [here](https://github.com/rivernews/appl-tracky-api/blob/master/django/api/filters.py#L83). While I can't provide context on the code since I haven't been working on that project, but hopefully the code or comment is self-explanatory or could give you some idea to get started.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have OneToOneField between this two model, if it's true, you can't have something like that because it's not logical

imagine that, if a user has a Demographic, and you retrieve allUsers, then for each one, we have one Demographic and it's not logical to filter one Demographic. the only way to do this is to filter it with the UserNode(as you said and did)

the Nested filtering just work if you have a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField to user model and then you can retrieve that in user with the separate filter

I hope I've been able to make it clear to you

Comment: Thanks but this example is also true for m2m and FK. Apparently graphene doesn't have this ability yet. (regardless of relationship type)

Comment: @morinx I have m2m and FK in my code and I do nested filter in it!

Comment: Yes, you can perform the filtering but the result is not exactly what you expect. Please see this issue for an example https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/410